# How to make SD card internal storage on android 7.0?

Tags: internal-sd

I have an LG Stylo 2 and the option to change internal storage to SD card isn't there.. I tried ADB method in this article

[How to format to SD card[1](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-format-microsd-cards-as-internal-storage)

But nothing happen. Any other ideas?

Comment: It is my understanding that LG turns this feature off

Comment: Can we get to know how you reached this understanding?